# Transferring variables between classes

Tags: python, class, variables, class-variables

I have 2 classes that operate on the same variables but do the inverse of each other. Is there a way to transfer the variables between them without hard coding every exchange or combining all the values into one array? Combining the classes is not an option.

```
#pseudocode

class class1:
   def __init___(self):
      # code
      initialize variable MAIN

   # do stuff
   # do stuff
   make variable stuff
   # do stuff
   make variable thing
   # do stuff

class class2:
   def __init___(self):
      # code
      initialize variable stuff
      initialize variable thing
   # do stuff
   # do stuff
   undo variable stuff
   # do stuff
   undo variable thing
   # do stuff
   make variable MAIN
```

I want to be able to send data back and forth between `class1` to `class2` quickly.

Comment: An example of what you are talking about could be helpful. "Do the inverses"? "Transfer variables"?

Comment: Yeah, so do it! What have you tried, and why didn't that work?

Comment: It's quite unclear what exactly you mean. Can you post a working example?

Answer (score 2):

Put the shared data into a third object and reference it from both classes.

Comment: i specifically said that putting the data into a third object doesnt work. edit: well, it does, but its not elagant at all

Comment: Well, no you didn't say that. :) You said that *combining* them didn't work. Different thing.

Comment: @calccrypto: "but its not elagant at all".  False.  It's very elegant and it solves all of your problems nicely through simple refactoring.

Comment: @S.Lott It would be even more elegant to transfer all instance variables with corresponding names from one class to another class. I think that's what this question is asking how to do, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is much easier than you think. Here is some examples of "sending" data between two classes.

```
class class2(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other = other

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color
        # "Sending" to other class:
        self.other.color = color

    def set_smell(self, smell, associated_object):
        self.smell = smell
        associated_object.smell = smell
```

Usage like this:

```
>>> ob1 = class1()
>>> ob2 = class2(ob1)
>>> ob2.set_color("Blue")
>>> ob1.color
"Blue"

>>> ob2.set_smell("Good", ob1)
>>> ob1.smell
"Good"
```

Comment: wait... how did self.other.color get to ob1?

Comment: @calccrypto: Oups, I misspelled. Fixed. self.other *is* ob1.

Comment: And I got a minus on this!? Hah, people are funny. (Doesn't matter, I hit my reputation limit today anyway, so no points lost. :) )

Comment: @calccrypto: Yeah, I didn't think it was you. It's just funny, that's all.